# CSS and images does't work on host

Tags: php, html, css, hosting

on my computer the website works fine.
when I upload the website the the server the images and css does't work.
I've tried to solve this problem myself but failed.

Comment: 99.99% likley its a path issue

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce (or show) it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://islam-ezzat.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: the paths are wrong, where you say the image files and css fires are in the html of you page is not where the files are on the server.

Answer (score -1):

I had some problem. Do not upload site with file zila or total commander they can loose some files.
Upload site directly using c-panel, zip-it and upload. 
If this dont work call administrator